# A separable locally compact group that is not metrizable and not compact

Tags: topological-groups

Hausdorffness assumed.

All the usual suspects don't work: $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{R}$, $2^\mathbb{R}$, discrete $\mathbb{R}$, etc.

My reasoning so far: if it is locally compact, then there are separable compact neighborhoods; of these, the ones that I know that are non-metrizable are uncountable copies of compact spaces such as $2$ or $[0,1]$. So, how to modify these so that they are only locally compact? Maybe $\beta\mathbb{Z}$ with a missing point?

Comment: You probably mean $2^\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ because discrete $\mathbb{R}$ is not separable.

Comment: What's wrong with $2^\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z$?